# vb sum column in array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sum

i have problem with summing up a column in a multiple column array.

I have this code

```
Dim sum As Integer
Dim v As Integer
    For Each v In array
        sum = sum + v
    Next v
```

But this code sums up the whole array. Anyone who can tell me how to only sum op one column? It is for visual studio- not Excel!

Best Regards

Btw

This is how the array is populatet

```
Dim array(100, 4) As Integer

For h = 1 To 5
    For j = 11 To Common.GlobalCounter + 9
        If Form1.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls("GroupBox" & 1).Controls("labRun" & j & h).Text = "" Then
            array(j - 10, h - 1) = 0
        Else
            array(j - 10, h - 1) = Form1.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls("GroupBox" & 1).Controls("labRun" & j & h).Text
        End If
    Next
Next
```

It is the values from allot if textboxes

Comment: Can you provide the full code? How is array declared

Comment: @ose this is now done

Comment: you need to turn on Option Strict

Comment: Don't names variables the same as `DataTypes`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim sum As Integer = 0
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim column As Integer = some value '0-4

For i = 0 To array.GetLength(0) - 1 'get row length
    sum += array(i, column)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get the error:
'Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array'

What am i doing wrong?